# Allow KVM guests on virsh virtual network to access the real internal network

Tags: linux, networking, routing, kvm, virsh

I have a home network 192.168.1.0 behind a router 192.168.1.1.  A set of existing Linux and Windows hosts are on this network, most on wired ethernet connections.  I am configuring a new server that runs a KVM hypervisor and 3 Debian guests.  The new server uses wifi for network connectivity.

On the hypervisor, I used `virsh` to configure a virtual network like this:

```
<network>
  <name>virtual</name>
  <forward mode='route'/>
  <ip address='192.168.2.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.2.2' end='192.168.2.255'/>
      <host mac='52:54:00:00:00:01' ip='192.168.2.2'/>
      <host mac='52:54:00:00:00:02' ip='192.168.2.3'/>
      <host mac='52:54:00:00:00:03' ip='192.168.2.4'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

Then, I created a static route in my router from 192.168.2.0/24 to the hypervisor's IP address of 192.168.1.41.

When I created the Debian guests, I specified the virtual network name and the MAC addresses from the `virsh` virtual network, like this:

```
--network network=virtual,mac=52:54:00:00:00:01
```

This results in `/etc/network/interfaces` like this on each guest:

```
iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.2.2
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   network 192.168.2.0
   broadcast 192.168.2.255
   gateway 192.168.2.1
```

With this configuration in place, things mostly work.  I can:

- Connect from hosts on 192.168.1.0 to both hypervisor IP addresses (.2.1 and .1.41)
- Connect from hosts on 192.168.1.0 to each guest
- Connect from the hypervisor to each guest
- Connect from each guest to the hypervisor (.2.1) and to each other guest
- Connect from each guest to the public internet
- Forward external (internet) connections from the router to individual guests

However, I *cannot* connect from the guests to any host on the 192.168.1.0 network.  For instance, I can't ssh from 192.168.2.2 to 192.168.1.31.

A `traceroute` shows something like this:

```
traceroute to 192.168.1.31 (192.168.1.31), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  sol (192.168.2.1)  0.295 ms  0.252 ms  0.243 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
```

I am not sure whether my configuration is incorrect, or whether I might be running into a problem with the wireless access point.

I've tried adding `ebtables` configuration (as discussed [here](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections)) to do MAC translation, but that did not make any difference.  I've attempted to add a separate bridge network device outside of `virsh`, but the existing virtual devices cannot be attached to any other bridges.  I've considered other options like a `virsh` filter or perhaps some iptables rules, but I'm grasping at straws.

Can someone suggest the right way to approach this?

Comment: For what it's worth (two years later), I now think that this is probably something specific to the ASUS RT-N66U router I have been using.  I switched to a different router running OpenWrt, and now the guests on the 192.168.2 network can ping devices on the 192.168.1 network.